# How to scale proportionally in after effects

Tags: adobe-after-effects

[image]Hey. I am using ae 2018 version on mac platform. Trying to scale shape by holding shift key, but its streches automaticly.

How it looks with holding shift you can see on this image.

Comment: A few tips:
- start scaling, then press shift

Answer (score 0):

### Selection Tool + Shift

Make sure you have the **Selection Tool** selected (**Cmd+V**), then hold down **Shift** while dragging from any corner.

In the animated image, you can see how it becomes constrained/proportionate as soon as I hold down **Shift**.

This will shape proportionally no matter what the [aspect ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_(image)) as seen in this demo.

### [image]

Comment: The problem was, that aspect ratio something like 1:3, just changed to 1:1

Comment: I've updated the video to better reflect the issue.

It shouldn't do. But make sure you don't hold down shift after resizing. It will only scale proportionally on the original shape you clicked on. Get the desired shape first, then click and resize proportionally after that.